Missing argument for parameter 'sessionClient' in call
I'm encountering a problem in my view file Missing argument for parameter 'sessionClient' in call Basically I'm using dependency which calls VideoQualityViewModel to retrieve subscription types and filter according to subscription to display the type of video quality available Here's the structure
class VideoQualityViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var allOptions: [VideoQualityOption] = VideoQualityEnum.allCases.map { $0.toVideoQualityOption() }
    @Published var availableVideoQualityOptions: [VideoQualityOption] = []
    @Published var selectedVideoQualityOption: VideoQualityOption?

    private let sessionClient: SessionClient

    init(dependencyContainer: Container, sessionClient: SessionClient) {
        self.sessionClient = sessionClient
        configureOptions()
        setDefaultOption()
    }

    private func configureOptions() {
        // Configure the available video quality options based on the user's rights
        let userRight = sessionClient.currentAppSessionState.userRight

        switch userRight {
        case .short, .basic:
            // Users with basic or short rights cannot access "Full HD"
            availableVideoQualityOptions = allOptions.filter { $0.id != VideoQualityEnum.fullHD.name }
        case .max:
            // Users with max rights have access to all options
            availableVideoQualityOptions = allOptions
        }
    }

    private func setDefaultOption() {
        selectedVideoQualityOption = availableVideoQualityOptions.first { $0.id == VideoQualityEnum.automatique.name }
    }

    func saveSelectedQuality() {
        // Saves the selected option and prints its name
        guard let selectedOption = selectedVideoQualityOption else { return }
        print("Saved video quality: \(selectedOption.name)")
    }
}

the view
#Preview {
    let container = Swinject.Container()
    container.register(VideoQualityViewModel.self) { _ in
        return VideoQualityViewModel(dependencyContainer: container)
    }
    let viewModel: VideoQualityViewModel = container.resolve(VideoQualityViewModel.self)!
    VideoQualityView(videoQualityViewModel: viewModel)
}

here I have the error
Missing argument for parameter 'sessionClient' in call
I also use a presentable in my AppSettingsmodule file
func videoQualityPresentable() -> Presentable {
        let sessionClient = dependencyContainer.resolve(SessionClient.self).unwrapOrFatal("SessionClient not injected")
        let viewModel = VideoQualityViewModel(dependencyContainer: dependencyContainer, sessionClient: sessionClient)
        let viewController = UIHostingController(rootView: VideoQualityView(videoQualityViewModel: viewModel))
        viewController.title = "Qualité Vidéo"
        return createPresentable(viewController: viewController)
    }

Thank you for your help
I have an error in the view now and not in the AppSettingsModule

You'll have better luck with SwiftUI if you remove the custom view model object and learn the built-in State and Binding for your view data.
